# Angular - ngrx, switchMap on error further subscriptions not fired

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have ngrx store in  my angular app. Here is my component init function.

```
ngOnInit() {

 this.$appState = this.appState.getIndex().pipe(switchMap((index) => {
      // do something and return subscription
      return this.someService.getItem(index);
    }), switchMap((data) => {
      return this.someOtherService.getItemDetails(data.index);
    })).subscribe((item: any) => {

});
```

On state change, when component is active (not destroyed), the component will subscribe to the `appState.getIndex` and get latest item and gets latest itemDetails. This is works fine as long as the `this.someService.getItem(index);` and `this.someOtherService.getItemDetails(data.index)` returns 200. There are some items, which doesn't have details or item at all then the calls returns 404. After that any further changes to state is not firing the subscription  calls. Not sure, what exactly my mistake is. Could some one please point my mistake.

Comment: try piping in a catchError operator

Answer (score 0):

each of your requests should handle their own errors most of the time.

```js
    ngOnInit() {

     this.$appState = this.appState.getIndex().pipe(switchMap((index) => {
          // do something and return subscription
          return this.someService.getItem(index).pipe(
              catchError(err => handlerror(err))
             );
        }), switchMap((data) => {
          return this.someOtherService.getItemDetails(data.index).pipe(
              catchError(err => handlerror(err))
             );
        })).subscribe((item: any) => {

    });
```